# How to find the least common multiple

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does anyone has the method to find the least common multiple between $11$ and $28$?
I've just started a course algebraic notion and I don't know how to use this powerful tool.

Comment: $11$ is a prime and does not divide $28$. Hence $gcd=1$ and $lcm=11\times28$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recipe that reads:

$${\rm LCM}(a,b)=\frac{|ab|}{{\rm GCD}(a,b)}$$

Comment: take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Computing_the_least_common_multiple for examples

Comment: You mean the LCM  "of",not  "between". It's the usual terminology. Any time I hear "between" I tend to think of an interval, although in non-math , "between" has other uses .Do you know Euclid's algorithm for the GCD?

Comment: put your questions here if you want. I mean on the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

If you know the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*, which gives the coefficients of a Bézout's relation for the g.c.d., proceeding one step further, you get the l.c.m.

Indeed the last step for the g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$ gives
$$d=ua+vb \quad (\lvert u\rvert<b, \enspace\lvert v\rvert<a)$$
and one step further the division is exact, hence you get
$$0=xa+yb \quad (\lvert x\rvert<b, \enspace\lvert y\rvert<a)$$
This proves that
$$\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=\lvert xa\rvert=\lvert yb\rvert$$